# Hide or disable Tomcat command line arguments logging

Tags: jvm, environment-variables, tomcat8, keystore, password-encryption

Our application server (**Apache Tomcat Plume**) that use jta-managed data source through tomee.xml file should access database server just in secure (HTTPS) mode with two way ssl or client authentication.
So we have to put **keystore** and **truststore** *plain passwords* into **setenv.sh** or other places in **row format**. (I m not sure that is the first and last method to do that?) and what happens is tomcat logging mechanism log all these secret information in plain format into log files like **catalina.out**.

---

That what (**locating raw passwords in config files**) is we do not want. Actually we must ( although it s not appear a big threaten while user have access to files, could find real password atleast), **encrypt password and use it in environment variables**.

### Central Question

In other word, how can we set jvm properties and environment variables in encrypted mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Re: *Hide or disable Tomcat command line arguments logging* (the title of this question)

This logging is done by `VersionLoggerListener` it is possible to [configure](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/listeners.html#Version_Logging_Lifecycle_Listener_-_org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener) it, or just remove it from configuration (`server.xml`).

Re: *plaintext passwords handling*

This is covered in [Tomcat FAQ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Password).

A Vault can be used to store secrets.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks brother.

Comment: I added -DlogArgs=false in my command line args and i'm still seeing my command line arguments being logged?

Comment: How would I add logArgs=false in my server.xml file?

Comment: @ChrisF: Replace  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/> with thes line if exist:  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" logArgs="false"/>

Comment: Thanks @Erfankam, that's what I ended up doing.